# How are programs written in Unicode?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, javac

From the Java Specification SE 7 Edition

§3.1 **Unicode**

> *Programs are written using the Unicode character set.*

§3.2 **Lexical Translations**

> *A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of
>   tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps...*

I'm confused because I write my source code with my native character encoding (Windows-1252), and the specification mentions that (?) all begins from a raw Unicode character stream, then the lexical translations (Unicode escape conversion included) are performed.

They mention that Unicode escapes can be used to include any Unicode character using
only ASCII characters; if a previous conversion is performed, I think they refer to ASCII characters in the subset of the Unicode character set, which makes sense.

Is there a previous conversion from the encoding used to write the source file to Unicode?

Some information related but I think that is more kind of a text handling at runtime, rather than the compilation process:

[Converting Non-Unicode Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/convertintro.html)

Comment: Presumably your compiler will be able to convert your source code file *into* an internal unicode representation. The format of the actual, physical file shouldn't matter for the purpose of the language specification.

Comment: CP-1252 is an **encoding** and the specification talks about the **character set**. All characters supported by CP-1252 are indeed contained in the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what the spec is saying is that you can only use Unicode characters in your source files. It doesn't define how those characters are actually encoded into bytes, that's up to you and the platform you're working on.

Basically what happens inside the compiler is that a source file is read from disk as a stream of bytes, those bytes are then converted to Java's internal representation of Unicode characters. The way it translates the raw bytes of the source file to Unicode characters is based on the `-encoding` option passed to `javac`. If no `-encoding` option is set it will use your platform's default encoding.

Now it's also important to note that after the compiler translates the source code bytes into characters it then does another step to convert character literals (e.g. `\u00a5123`) into the appropriate single Unicode character. This is actually the first of the three steps referenced in section 3.2 that you quoted in your question. This way it's possible using nothing but plain ASCII characters to represent any Unicode character in your source.

Comment: Does that mean you could literally write all your source with these:  \u00a5123 ?

Comment: @RobertMarkBram I'm not sure about Java, but C and C++ allow Unicode escapes as well but prohibit them from being used for characters in the basic source character set outside of string and character literals. I would guess that Java has the same restriction, and so you cannot write your code that way.

Comment: @RobertMarkBram Hello World program using escapes sequences: http://ideone.com/EqD25

Comment: \u0057\u0068\u0079\u0020\u0077\u006F\u0075\u006C\u0064\u0020\u0079\u006F\u0075\u0020\u0077\u0061\u006E\u0074\u0020\u0074\u006F\u0020\u0064\u006F\u0020\u0074\u0068\u0061\u0074\u003F

Comment: @nEAnnam Wow, I guess Java doesn't have a prohibition against that. Yet another mistake in Java's specification for UCNs. (another being that Java uses surrogate pairs of UCNs to represent characters outside the BMP.)

Comment: @bames53 Not sure why you consider that a mistake. Character literals are basically an extension of encoding and should be translated before any parsing/lexing occurs. I do agree that surrogates are a pain, but that issue is really rooted in the fact that Java exposes primitives instead of just making everything an object.

Comment: I consider it a mistake because it allows people to obfuscate code for no good reason. It simply is not a useful facility. C++ made the right call here. Also I don't think the surrogates issue has anything to do with Java's design. It's simply that in the 90s people were making all kinds of mistakes with Unicode. It's the same reason UCS-2 and UTF-16 exist in the first place and why anyone actually uses them even though in hind-sight they're pointless.

Answer (score 2):

'Unicode' is not an encoding, it is simply a list of characters and associated numbers (or 'codepoints'), but unlike legacy character sets the numbers are not the on-disk representation of the Unicode characters. To encode or decode Unicode characters you need a separate encoding which maps from byte sequences to Unicode numbers and thus to Unicode characters.

Some encodings, like UTF-8, are designed to encode all possible Unicode code points. Others, like Windows CP 1252, can only represent a small subset of Unicode characters. But any valid Windows CP 1252 data can still be decoded into a valid sequence of Unicode codepoints.

So, yes, there is a conversion from the on-disk representation into a virtual Unicode character stream.

Comment: yeah, How Unicode is treated (Charset or encoding) leads to confusion, but look at the link that i've posted (official documentation), they say:  *Unicode is a 16-bit character encoding that supports the world's major languages* so i dont know how to refer it, thanks for the advice

Comment: That documentation is incorrect. Even if we refrain from nitpicking the reference to Unicode as an encoding then they're still wrong to say it's '16-bit'. In fact Unicode codepoints can require up to 21 bits when represented in binary. The Unicode Consortium has promised not to use larger values in order to remain compatible with UTF-16, but prior to this Unicode could have used values up to 31 bits for compatibility with UTF-32 and UTF-8 (6-byte version). If there were no desire to remain compatible with any of these encodings then there'd be no limit